# Iterate through a string using split

Tags: string, python-3.x, loops

I essentially have two list containing strings:

```
com = ['746365', '6365']
dec = ['6d955s2359d757bb40d0cf36bd7a35662d8b3']
```

I take the length of the first element in list a '746365' and cut list b into the same length as the first element, (len('746365') = 6) and the result of b is '6d955s'. I now wish to move along the element in b by one place until i reach the end ('62d8b3').

I currently have:

```
count = 0
for a in com:
    for b in dec:
        print(com.index(a), a)
        length_of = len(a)
        print(b[0 + count:length_of + count])
        count = count + 1
```

This doesn't work. However if I remove the count parts and leave whats displayed beneath it works but I can't get it to move along by one

```
for a in com:
    for b in dec:
        print(com.index(a), a)
        length_of = len(a)
        print(b[0:length_of])
```

how can I adjust this code so that I print then move along by one and print the next?

The initial result should be:

> ```
> 6d955s d955s2 955s23 etc etc..
> ```

once the end of dec has been reached, it'll move onto the next value in com.

Thanks.

Comment: What is happening instead?

Comment: @Taegost I just can't think of another way to implement it, it doesn't work with the count

Comment: I think what you want to do is "sliding window". You can look that term up on the web to find interesting stuff. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for a in com:
    for b in dec:
        for i in range(0,len(b)-len(a)+1):
            clipped_str = b[i:i+len(a)]
            print(clipped_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
start = 0
for c_element in com:
    current_length = len(c_element)
    end = start + current_length
    for d_element in dec:
        for _ in range(len(d_element) - current_length + 1):
            print(d_element[start:end])
            start += 1
            end += 1
    else:
        start = 0
```